# Is there an ALL siblings selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, siblings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS all inclusive sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426160/css-all-inclusive-sibling-selector)

CSS3 has an [*adjacent* sibling selector +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), and a [*general* sibling selector ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).  Is it possible to select *all* siblings? (the "general" selector actually only selects the *following* siblings)

For example, in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/9aU6D/1/), I would like all the non-hovered a-tags to get smaller, not just the tags that follow the hovered one.

**HTML**

```
<a href='#'>Item 1</a>
<a href='#'>Item 2</a>
<a href='#'>Item 3</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a { font-size: 15px; }
a:hover ~ a { font-size: 12px; }​
```

Comment: @refp: Ironically, a question that I answered too. The scenarios seem to be very different, though, enough to warrant a different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such sibling selector in Selectors 3.

Although you can select elements that aren't being hovered using the `:not()` pseudo-class, as `a:not(:hover)`, you can't select all of them relatively to some other `a` that is currently being hovered or only while it is being hovered.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are wrapped in a common parent, then you can approximate something similar:

```
#parent a {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#parent:hover a {
    font-size: 1em;
}

#parent:hover a:hover {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HpYFr/).

But, as answered by Boltclock, there's no (current) sibling-based CSS combinator/selector solution to the problem unfortunately.