# CSS get other set of elements when pseudo-selectors occur

Tags: css

Here's a short version of my html:

```
<div id="section1" class="section">...</div>
<div id="section2" class="section">...</div>
<div id="section3" class="section">...</div>
<div id="section4" class="section">...</div>
```

One of these sections will be a target for the `:target` pseudo-selector, and I currently want to select all siblings of the target. For one, [I know that CSS has no "all siblings" selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426160/css-all-inclusive-sibling-selector), just the general `~` and the adjacent `+` sibling combinator.

So instead, I want to find out of there was a way (or closest way) for CSS to get another set of elements (in this case, the siblings) only if the pseudo-selector happened.

```
.section:target then .section:not(:target){
  //apply to all .section not being the target
}
```

If I were to use jQuery, it's something like:

```
//if a section was a target
if($('.section:target').length > 0){
  //get all sections that are not the target
  $('.section:not(:target)').css({
    //apply css to them
  });
}
```

I have to note that the styles only happen if there is a target. If there's no target, then the styles should not be applied.

Comment: `~` is the 'general-sibling' combinator, not 'forward.' And no, this isn't possible, since since without selecting the parent element in order to select all child elements, there's no way to select previous elements. If the parent has a predictable selector then it *may* be possible, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your requirement/intent.

Comment: @DavidThomas it's a bit misleading as to why they call it "general" when it does not get all siblings, just the ones after the referenced selector.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's its name. And it does do exactly what its name implies, within the usual constraints of selecting only subsequent elements within the DOM.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you can't just do this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lvtga

Comment: Ah ok I think I got you, no style when there is no given target, hmmm...