# Css3 animation on divs

Tags: html, css

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uday_redI/V9F7d/2/) where there is a small css3 animation where there are 2 divs triggerBox controls the animation of another div the animateBox, It is working but once I rewrite the html from,

```
<div id="triggerBox"></div>
<div id="animateBox"></div>
```

to,

```
<div id="animateBox"></div>
<div id="triggerBox"></div>
```

It stops working, Can anyone help me up with the reason for this behavior?

And yes please do not give any solutions based on javascript unless its inevitable.

Comment: could have to do with cascading. In the sense that triggerbox needs to be in the dom before animatebox for the animation to work.

Comment: This is a problem with sibling selectors not looking back up the DOM tree. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426160/css-all-inclusive-sibling-selector

Comment: the reason is `#triggerBox:active ~ #animatorBox`. `~` is for general successor sibling (meaning the element comes after this one, but not necessarily immediately after) and is a CSS3 selector.

Comment: @AamirAfridi i didnt get your point

Comment: Thanks for the question I finally caught up with CSS2/3 you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `general sibling selector` in your CSS. If you read it correctly, it works only if the `#animatorBox` is after the `#triggerBox`, and they must share the same parent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Sorry to say, there is no `previous sibling selector` available at this moment.

Comment: pre sib selector would be very handy!

Comment: I agree, I believe those kind of selectors are being discussed in CSS4. http://css4-selectors.com/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V9F7d/5/)?

```
<div id="animatorBox"></div>
<div id="triggerBox"></div>

#animatorBox {
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:black;

}
#triggerBox {

    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}
#animatorBox:active ~ #triggerBox {
    width:10px;
}
```